# Rails catch-all route prevents calls to /rails/info/routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I'm working on a Rails project which uses a catch-all route primarily for rendering out an Angular front-end page.. Because this catch-all route is in the project, I've now lost the ability to hit /rails/info/routes which is somewhat handy to have.

Here's the relevant portion of my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  match "/delayed_job" => DelayedJobWeb, :anchor => false, via: [:get, :post]

  namespace :api, format: false, defaults: {format: :json} do
    .....
    get '*path' => 'base#not_found'
  end

  namespace :admin, format: false, except: [:show] do
    .....
    root 'home#index'
  end

  devise_for :users

  get 'styleguide' => 'styleguide#index'
  get '*path' => 'bootstrap#index'
  root 'bootstrap#index'

end
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `rake routes` in your terminal instead?

Comment: That has been my workaround and usually what I would do anyway... Just wondering if there is a way that other people get around this.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out - for anyone who runs into this you can add a contstraint where the request does NOT begin with /rails :

```
  get '*path' => 'bootstrap#index', constraints: -> (req) { !(req.fullpath =~ /^\/rails\/.*/) }
```

Comment: `req.fullpath.start_with?('/rails')` will be faster (and might be more readable) than a regexp.